# calling go net.InterfaceAddrs() fails on Android SDK 30+

Tags: android, go, gomobile, gomobile-android

The issue [40569](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40569) makes Golang (mobile binding) incompatible with Android SDK 30+. Calling the stdlib function net.InterfaceAddrs() gives an error due to changes made in Android SDK 30.

Discussion suggests that it can be resolved by modifying go source. I followed the instructions as per [this](https://github.com/golang/go/issues/40569#issuecomment-1603916131) comment, and created the mobile binding using 'gomobile bind ...' ensuring that the modified go source build is used (present in GOPATH and GOROOT). But I'm still getting the same error (route ip+net: netlinkrib: permission denied) on Android SDK 33. Does 'gomobile bind' (gobind) use their own Go binary instead of our installation to create bindings ?

Does somebody have a better idea to resolve this ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm unable to use modified go library for 'gomobile bind' to resolve the issue in Android, for some reason gomobile bind doesn't use modified go library installed in system.